# Using AWS to test Windows application

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, desktop-application

I am developing a Desktop Application (C#) and I would like a VM hosts to test it in different environment, like Windows 10 and 8.

How is the best way to achieve this in AWS?

Comment: Have you looked at Azure?  MS is better about licensing its own OSs to its own cloud platform.   I haven't tried that myself, for desktop application testing we use desktop VM software (VMWare, VirtualBox)

Comment: Azure can support Windows 10 if you already have a license and there is no support for Windows 8 (see [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-stack/azure-stack-supported-os) for details).  AWS only provides "server" O/S's like Server 2019, 2012, etc.  Unless you can spin up a Docker container with those desktop O/S's a cloud based environment may not be the right answer.